# What does ":" do in Python

Tags: python, tensorflow

I was trying to the understand basic Tensorflow functions in `cifar10.py` keras lib, function `load_batch`:

```
for i in range(1, 6):
    fpath = os.path.join(path, 'data_batch_' + str(i))
    (x_train[(i - 1) * 10000:i * 10000, :, :, :],
      y_train[(i - 1) * 10000:i * 10000]) = load_batch(fpath)
```

What does `":"` mean in the line below?

```
x_train[(i - 1) * 10000:i * 10000, :, :, :]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `x_train` etc are numpy array or similar structure which implement their interface. 
Here you can read about slicing in numpy https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html

Or more generic about slicing in python https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations